# Reading Tiff files in Adobe Flex based Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tiff

can some one help me in reading TIFF files at runtime in Flex/AS3 based applications?

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a TIFF reader written in ActionScript, it's not built into the framework or player.  Google Code Search offers a few options:

http://google.com/codesearch?q=tiff+lang%3Aactionscript&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code

This one looks most promising:

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ADyxW5M5wHw/trunk/TD/src/tiff/Tiff.as&q=tiff%20lang:actionscript&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc

Comment: thanks dude, looks solid to me, i was writing a utility that converts tiffs to Jpg on the fly at server bcz was very short in time for writing a tiff reader, but thanks again

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/windowsbitmapdencoder

Here is a tiff - baseline decoder I wrote back in july.
It will read all "baseline" formats, 1, 8, 24 bpp.
It will handle Intel/Motorolla byte order as well as interlace or planar pixel order.
However, it does not support compression yet.

But feel free to append !

I have started working on LZW and ZIP and can offer you the source code of implementation.

Sincerely,

CT

Comment: @CT: yeah i saw that when googling around & i loved it. but the problem was compression as the tiffs we were receiving were compressed ones. so for current flow, we have created a C# utility that automatically converts the multi frame tiffs into jpgs. but i will love to go for all AS3 based solution & avoid dependency on any other 3rd party utilities.